# Largest Coprime Divisor

Tags: java, logic

You are given two positive numbers A and B. You need to find the maximum valued integer X such that:  X divides A i.e. A % X = 0 X and B are co-prime i.e. gcd(X, B) = 1For example,  A = 30 B = 12 We return X = 5

Here in this code cpFact returns the required output. The best case is that when gcd(int A, int B)=1, so the actual value of A will be returned. Otherwise, while loop iterates to get desired output, at each time reducing the value of A by dividing it by gcd(A, B). But I didn't get the logic of why A reduced by dividing it with gcd(A, B). Can anyone please explain the logic behind it?

```
public class Solution 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(cpFact(48,16));
    }
    public static int cpFact(int A, int B) 
    {
     while(gcd(A, B)!=1
     {
         A=A/gcd(A, B);
     }
        return A;
    }
    public static int gcd(int X,int B)
        {
            if(X == 0)
              return B;
            return gcd(B%X,X);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you divide A by the greatest common denominator of A and B, then you obtain a new value A1 that has all the same denominators as A, except for this one (see explanation at bottom).

At the same time, A1 divides A by definition.

Then you can replace A with A1 and proceed to examine the rest of its common denominators with B in descending order, until there's only `1` left, which means that the last examined value of A is the answer.

*Explanation for first sentence:*

Imagine A and B can be written:

```
A = a * d * e
B = a * b * c * e * f
  where a > b > c > d > e > f
```

Then the greatest common denominator (GCD) of `(A,B)` is `a`. This means that if you divide `A` by `a`, then you obtain `A1 = A / a = d * e`.

`A` is dividable by `A1` (because `A / A1 = a`), and you can now find the GCD of `(A1,B)`, that will be `e`, the next common denominator of `(A,B)` in descending order.